# Every time I open the VPN, my Golang debugger fails to execute and shows the following message:

Tags: go, debugging

Every time I open the VPN, my Golang debugger fails to execute and shows the following message:

```
D:\Program Files\go\go1.18.5\bin\go.exe tool test2json -t 
D:\Program Files\JetBrains\GoLand 2023.1.1\plugins\go-plugin\lib\dlv\windows\dlv.exe --listen=127.0.0.1:51782 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false exec 
C:\Users\j'j\AppData\Local\JetBrains\GoLand2023.1\tmp\GoLand\___1server_controller__TestGetGoodsSubTypeNum.test.exe -- -test.v -test.paniconexit0 -test.run ^\QTestGetGoodsSubTypeNum\E$ #gosetup

API server listening at: 192.168.1.11:51782
2023-06-28T16:00:27+08:00 warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
```

Normally, it listens on 127.0.0.1:51782.

I am using GoLand 2023.1.1 software.

After restarting the computer without opening the VPN software, it functions normally.

Comment: It passes `--listen=127.0.0.1:51782` to `dlv` but `dlv` listens on `192.168.1.11:51782` instead. That's weird. What's the version of the `dlv`? And which VPN software do you use?

Comment: [This](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-8691/Goland-debugger-not-starting) looks very much like what you see.

Can you reproduce the issue with delve only, without Goland IDE?